# adjunctions from either the category of small categories or the category of groupoids

Tags: category-theory, examples-counterexamples, adjoint-functors, groupoids

I'm looking for examples of adjunctions involving either the category **Gpd** of groupoids or the category **Cat** of small categories.

The insertion of **Gpd** into **Cat** has both a left and a right adjoint, so any adjunction involving one of the two can be composed to give a new adjunction involving the other instead.

I know a few easy ones already:

- adjunctions involving the category **Set** of sets
- taking the free category on a directed graph
- taking the nerve of a category as a simplicial set

As a related question, **Cat** has a full subcategory **SkCat** of skeletal categories.  Does the insertion of **SkCat** into **Cat** admit an adjoint?  Obviously we can ask the same for **SkGpd**.

Comment: Somewhat related: I am just wondering whether any category can be decomposed into a groupoid and a skeletal category in a suitable (reversible!) sense.

Comment: There is basically no hope for any kind of canonical construction of the skeleton of a category or groupoid – their existence is equivalent to the axiom of choice, after all.

Comment: The category $\mathbf{Cat}$ is Cartesian closed, so for any category $\mathscr{C}$ the functors $(-) \times \mathscr{C}$ and $[\mathscr{C},-]$ describe adjoints from $\mathbf{Cat}$ to $\mathbf{Cat}$.